# Regex - match string NOT containing one group, DOES contain another

Tags: regex, perl

For example, a regular expression that matches a string that does not contain "foo" but does contain "bar". I do not have the luxury of using two expressions. I need to do it in one expression.

ex.:

> "this is foo baz bar" - should not match
> "this is foo baz" - should
>   not match
>  "this is baz bar" - should match

I'm in Perl, fwiw

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion at the start to check for the string not contain any `foo` substring.

```
^(?!.*?foo).*bar.*
```

OR

```
^(?!.*?\bfoo\b).*\bbar\b.*
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/bY7fC2/1)

Comment: awesome, thanks. the .* inside the negative lookahead group is what I had been missing.